# How to rewind an activity in wf4.0?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

Suppose there are 5 activities in workflow Service (xamlx) and 2nd and 5th activity need to run again by user by any control mechanism.
Please help me how to control this and how to re run those activities. Is flowchart a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to reset the execution pointer in a workflow. You need model the logic in your workflow.

Comment: Hi Maurice, I am waiting for your answer. My requirement is like as a  workflow hosted on iis with its control endpoint have some activity and  some of them can be re wind by  any external control mechanism. Please suggest me to how to achieve this?

Comment: Like I mentioned. You need to add the activities to receive the event and use conditional logic to either continue or loop back. just like any other decision you make about the execution flow in your workflow.